# How to make text disappear when mouse is not on object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mousemove

I have objects and they show texts when the mouse is over them. I used MOUSE_MOVE event for this. The problem is when mouse leaves the object, the text stays at the last position. I want it to disappear till the moment mouse will touch the object again. How to do it?

**EDIT**

I found out MOUSE_OUT or ROLL_OUT works very well. The only problem now is, when I'm on object and text shows up, when I move my mouse fast enough over the text, it blinks. I think it's because text is over the object and when I'm on text, I'm not on object anymore. So I'll just move the text a little away from the cursor. Thanks for answers :)

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import inventory.inventorySystem;
import inventory.item;
import flash.text.TextField;

var IS:inventorySystem;
var IT:item;

apple.itemName = "Apple";
apple.itemIcon = new AppleIcon();
apple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, showItemNameF);
apple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, hideItemNameF);

pear.itemName = "Pear";
pear.itemIcon = new PearIcon();
pear.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, showItemNameF);
pear.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, hideItemNameF);

function showItemNameF(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var itemNameBox:String;
    itemNameBox = item(e.currentTarget).itemName;
    stage.addChild(infoBoxObject);
    infoBoxObject.infoBox.text = itemNameBox;
    infoBoxObject.x = mouseX;
    infoBoxObject.y = mouseY;
}

function hideItemNameF(e:MouseEvent):void{
    infoBoxObject.x = -145;
    infoBoxObject.y = 61;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can make the Enabled to false and if the MouseOver-Event then enabled true.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MOUSE_MOVE event, please be aware that this event fires constantly while moving your mouse. This can in certain cases cause your app to slow down if you execute to much logic on this event. (just a side note)

If you are using MOUSE_MOVE, you could use the hitTestObject() to check if you're touching the text container (There are a lot of examples to be found out there on how to accomplish this).

Preferably, you would use a mouse enter and mouse leave event on the container of the text.

For more help you would need to give us some code examples.

Comment: @AnilDemir - If it worked - please accept the answer or let us know if you need more information.